# How do I search for a folder in a folder in c#?

Tags: c#, directory, datadirectory

I want to check if a specific folder exists in a folder in c#.
Currently I'm using the following code.

```
        string currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();

        foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(currentPath))
        {
            if (subDir == currentPath + @"\Database") // if "Database" folder exists
            {
                dbinRoot = true;
            }
        }
        if (dbinRoot == true)
        {
            currentPath = currentPath + @"\Database\SMAStaff.accdb";
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                currentPath = currentPath.Remove(currentPath.LastIndexOf("\\"));
            }
            currentPath = currentPath + "\\Database\\SMAStaff.accdb";
        }
```

I wish to know if there is a better way of doing this ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use:

```
Directory.Exists(currentPath + @"\Database")
```

Comment: I'd strongly advise using Path.Combine rather than using string concatenation to create folder paths

Answer (score 1):

It also more reliably to use `Path.Combine` method to concatenate parts of path

> if (Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"Database"))){}

Answer (score 0):

You are probably directly looking for

```
currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
bool fileExists = File.Exists(Path.Combine(currentPath, "Database\\SMAStaff.accdb")))
```

And the for cycle may contain for better readability

```
currentPath = Directory.GetParent(currentPath).FullName;
```